# merge a key which is tuple type with a value which is a list of tuple in one list of tuples, python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, iteration

I want to change dictionary with tuple key and list value to list either one list or lists based on the numbers of the keys we have

Example : 
as you can see tuple in the key and list of tuple in value .

```
input 
f = {('justin', '0'): [('fun', '1'), ('crazy', '2')],
 ('julie', '3'): [('fun', '4'), ('crazy', '5')]}

desired output1: 

f = [('justin', '0'),('fun', '1'), ('crazy', '2')],[('julie', '3'),('fun', '4'), ('crazy', '5')]

desired output1: 

 f = [('justin', '0'),('fun', '1'), ('crazy', '2'),('julie', '3'),('fun', '4'), ('crazy', '5')]
```

Comment: Try this: `result = list([key] + [v for v in value] for key,value in f.items())`. It will give you the first desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the key-value pairs for your first desired output, and then flatten to achieve the second:

```
f = {('justin', '0'): [('fun', '1'), ('crazy', '2')], ('julie', '3'): [('fun', '4'), ('crazy', '5')]}
desired_1 = [[a]+b for a, b in f.items()]
desired_2 = [i for b in desired_1 for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[[('justin', '0'), ('fun', '1'), ('crazy', '2')], [('julie', '3'), ('fun', '4'), ('crazy', '5')]]
[('justin', '0'), ('fun', '1'), ('crazy', '2'), ('julie', '3'), ('fun', '4'), ('crazy', '5')]
```